# which context to use in service?

Tags: android

I want to call method in some other class which need Context as input parameter but i have 3 possibility in service:

```
- getApplicationContext
- getBaseContext
- getApplication
```

Which one to use in `ScreenService` which `extends Service`

what is the main different. I read some times ago that is not good to use getApplicationContext. Is that true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Application context** is attached to the application's life-cycle and will always be same throughout the life of application. So if you are using Toast, you can use application context or even activity context (both) because a toast can be raised from anywhere with in your application and is not attached to a window.

**Activity context** is attached to the Activity's life-cycle and can be destroyed if the activity's onDestroy is raised.

`getApplication()` though its referring to Application object but the Application class extends Context class, so it can be used to offer application context.

`getApplicationContext()` offers application context.

`getBaseContext()` offers activity context.

It depends why you for which purpose you are using the context,

`getApplicationContext()` is most preferred way since this Context lives untill Application shuts down.

`getBaseContext()` Context is available to widgets and Views.

so in a toast message or when creating an intent, they all have the same effect eventhough using `getApplicationContext()` is the most correct. Toast accepts any kind of Context since its not attached any kind of View. Its a notification.